# Upload file using ajax to djangorest api?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I have a ajax call as below. Now I want to post data including file to the url /api/create/project created .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}


$(".project").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault()
      var image_file = document.getElementById('content');
      var myFile = image_file.files[0];
      console.log(myFile);
      var this_ = $(this);
      var form =  this_.serializeArray();
      console.log("form", this_);
      console.log(form);
      var formData =  this_.serialize();

        var temp=

        {
"title": form[1].value,
"project_question_content_url": myfile,
"deadline_date": form[2].value,
"employee": {{ id }},
"course": form[3].value
```

}

```
console.log(temp);
      $.ajax({
        url: "/api/project/create",
        data: JSON.stringify(temp),
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
  },

        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
           console.log(data)


        },
        error: function(data){
          console.log("error")
          console.log(data.statusText)
          console.log(data.status)
        }
      })

    });
    });
```

Now, How to send file through json in the temp variable? I have created api using rest framework.Also, we cannot get the url of file path for security reasons of js. The file upload from the rest works fine.
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using your own implementation for file upload in the browser, I'd suggest you use a package like https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload which will simplify your experience a great deal.  The primary issue is you have to handle attaching the file data to the XHR object, which requires a number of steps.  Using something like the file uploader widget linked above makes it much easier to integrate, and includes a number of nice features.

Once you have it working in the browser, integrating with your existing API should be easy, since you're pretty much all the way there.

Comment: Using jquery file upload It works but how can we send the file data through the ajax data?

Comment: You can look at how that lib does it

Comment: File upload does work with the library..Thanks for that!! But the url from the media folder which I sent through the ajax post method does not works.. Any idea?

Comment: that's a django issue, not front end.  Might want to make another question about it